# Import users from CSV file

Tags: users, user-management, csv

Is it possible to import users by using CSV file? or something like a LDAP connection to import all users?

Comment: Both is possible. For importing you'll need a script for running `adduser` or `useradd` for each user. For LDAP you need to configure PAM. I recommend to focus your question to one of these two solutions because they are so completely different

Comment: I cannot understand how a question like this, showing no effort at all, not following any of the site guidelines, can get upvotes at all, or even more than any of the documented answers.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @fedorqui can you elaborate please , where exactly the question fails ? I agree that OP didn't show any effort, but I don't see how this question is different from others "How do I do X and X ?" type of questions ?

Comment: @fedorqui "Is it possible to import users by using CSV file?" it's a good and legitime question.

Comment: @Serg then others are also bad :D I was astonished by the upvotes. Why? See the description when you hover on the upvote: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". The [original question](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/633695/1) does not show any effort at all (format, research, etc). More info in [How do I ask a good question](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @A.B. see comment above

Answer (score 15):

There's an app for that! The `newusers` tool which is part of the `passwd` package is designed to batch create users:

```
DESCRIPTION
   The newusers command reads a file (or the standard input by default)
   and uses this information to update a set of existing users or to
   create new users. Each line is in the same format as the standard
   password file (see passwd(5)) with the exceptions explained below:
```

You will need to create a file with this format:

```
username:passwd:UID:GID:full name,room number,work phone,home phone,other:directory:shell
```

Many of these can be ignored and the default values will be used. You only *need* to specify the username and password. For example:

```
tom:password1:::::
danny:password2:::::
```

If I save that as `users.txt` and run this command:

```
sudo newusers < users.txt
```

The users are created:

```
$ grep -E 'tom|danny' /etc/passwd
tom:x:1005:1006:::
danny:x:1006:1007:::
```

Comment: What if the password should contain a colon? =)

Comment: You have already my upvote, once again =)

Comment: @A.B. in that case, you need to use a different tool. I can't figure out how to have a colon in a password for `newuser`. Neither quoting, nor escaping seems to work :(

Comment: Are you sure it works? Last time I tried it failed as soon as there was more than one line in the file - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1266675.

Answer (score 10):

With a script you can. This needs a file with user and password commaseparated:

```
while IFS="," read -r user passwd ; do      
        echo "useradd -m -p $(mkpasswd "$passwd") $user"
done < /home/$USER/Downloads/users.txt
```

- `mkpasswd` can be installed with `sudo apt-get install whois`
- Change the , to a ; if you need that.

Save this as `users.sh` and set permissions with `chmod +x users.sh`

If you then do

```
./users.sh > users_create.sh
```

You get a text file with all the commands so you can verify it and

```
chmod +x users.sh
./users_create.sh
```

will then create them.

---

**Testing**

Example file:

```
wdn,password123 
wdn2,password345
```

saved as "users.txt" in "~/Downloads".

Execute script:

```
./users.sh 
useradd -m -p acBNi2tbw9iaw wdn
useradd -m -p OHOzeMGqbcMso wdn2
```

and

```
./users.sh  > users_create.sh
~/Downloads$ more users_create.sh 
useradd -m -p Q1BVotdoA3ucI wdn
useradd -m -p siUX7mYTYw.3A wdn2
```

(password are encrypted).

After this all you need to do is execute is to make this executable with `chmod +x users.sh` and execute it with `./users_create.sh` (I did not do that last bit so if not working please comment).

Comment: `for users in $(cat file)` is not the best way to loop in a file. Instead, just use `while IFS="," read -r user passwd ; do ... ; done < file`. `$user` and `$passwd` will contain the 1st and 2nd columns, etc.

Comment: Like so @fedorqui ? (feel free to edit it and help me beat  Serg ;) )

Comment: Yep, way better. I would also use `$()` instead of backticks, since they are preferred. Also, it is always good practice to quote variables when `echo`ing

Comment: What if the password should contain a comma? =)

Comment: Then you find another delimiter ;)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an awk one-liner:

`sudo awk -F',' '{ command="useradd -p $( mkpasswd "$2" ) "$1;print command; system(command) }' userlist.txt`

Or for readability, here's the format:

```
sudo awk -F',' '{ 
            command="useradd -p $(mkpasswd "$2 ")" $1; 
            print command; 
            system(command)
           }' userlist.txt
```

**Explanation**:

awk's `system` function allows running shell commands while awk is processing entries from text file. We create a variable "command" that is just text of the command we want to run. Using comma as field separator `-F','` , we take field #2 and #1 and place them to match syntax of the useradd command. Once the text of the command is assembled, system(command) executes `useradd -p $(mkpasswd password) username` , for each line of the text. `print command` part is optional, merely for debugging and verifying that all usernames have been processed

**Addition:**

The oneliner can be turned into an awk script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f


BEGIN {FS=",";}

{ 
     command="useradd -p $(mkpasswd "$2") " $1; 
     print command; 
    system( command )
}
```

Now make sure the script has executable permissions with `sudo chmod +x script-name.awk` and run it with any input file like so `sudo ./awkscript.sh userlist.txt` if it is in your current working directory, or you can call that script anywhere by placing it into one of the `$PATH` directories

**Possible `,` in the password**

To take into account possibility of having comma in password, I suggest you use `sub()` function. Sub function changes *first* instance of a character or word in each line. In other words, if we have an entry such as `testuser,foo,bar`, where `foo,bar` is password, and we change first entry to space, we can use awk normally , without telling it to use `-F','` flag. Awk will translate each entry to `testuser  foo,bar`, and treat testuser as $1 and foo,bar as $2. To put this into code:

`sudo awk  '{ sub(","," ");command="useradd -p $( mkpasswd "$2" ) "$1;print command; system(command) }' userlist.txt`

Comment: What if the password should contain a comma? =)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `python` solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess, crypt

with open('/path/to/file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        i = line.find(',')
        name = line[:i]
        password = line.rstrip()[i+1:]
        encpt_passwd = crypt.crypt(password, '2b')
        command = 'useradd -m -p {0} {1}'.format(encpt_passwd, name).split()
        subprocess.call(command)
```

This will handle passwords having commas.

- `line.find(',')` will find the lowest index of `,` in each line of the file
- `line[:i]` will take the slice of the line containg the username
- `line.rstrip()[i+1:]` will contain the password
- `crypt` module generates encrypted password from input of the form `crypt.crypt(password, salt)`. `encpt_passwd` will contain the encrypted password. In `crypt.crypt(password, '2b')`, `password` is the saved plain password and `2b` is the salt.
- `subprocess.call(command)` will simply run the command to generate users

Comment: Good job, hence +1, works even with comas in password

Comment: @Serg I have already given +1 to your one (and others)..

Comment: Common, accept a parameter for the CSV file :) anyway +1

Answer (score 2):

I have a shorter `awk` version (@Serg =)):

First install `whois`, we need the command `mkpasswd`

```
sudo apt-get install whois
```

Than you can use this oneliner:

```
awk -F',' '{print "Create user: "$1; system("sudo useradd -p $(mkpasswd "$2") "$1)}' users
```

or without any output:

```
awk -F',' '{system("sudo useradd -p $(mkpasswd "$2") "$1)}' users
```

---

Content of `users`:

```
foo,foopasswd
bar,password
foobar,foobar
```

The user name is in the first column, the unencrypted password in the 2nd column.

---

In fairness, I mention a problem here. Passwords can not include a comma.

Answer (score 1):

My AWK version has a problem with `,` in the password. Here is my perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
    binary    => 1, # Allow special character. Always set this
    auto_diag => 1, # Report irregularities immediately
    sep_char  => ','
});

while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    print "User: ".$row->[0]."\n";
    print "Password: ".$row->[1]."\n";

    my $hashed = crypt($row->[1], "salt");
    my $cmd = 'useradd -p '.$hashed.' '.$row->[0]."\n";

    system($cmd);
}
close $fh;
```

---

Example:

CSV file `users.csv`:

```
foo,"foopasswd"
bar,"password"
foobar,"""foo,bar"
```

Start the script

```
% sudo add_users users.csv
User: foo
Password: foopasswd
useradd -p sajllSNct/Wx2 foo

User: bar
Password: password
useradd -p sa3tHJ3/KuYvI bar

User: foobar
Password: "foo,bar
useradd -p saBWMpscG9WvA foobar
```