# how to create users on the fly

Tags: ssh, users

This is just a bad idea that I just had.

Is there a way create users accounts on the fly?

Say I have a Ubuntu vm created, and I want to give a bunch of people access. But for whatever reason I don't particularly care about what they do with it.

How can I set it up that when user A ssh into the vm the user's account will automatically be created?

and yes, I know in theory, I could just create a guest account and share that with the people that need access. but then a bunch of people will be sharing the account and I also want to log what everybody did so having them on the same account would make it very difficult.

and yes, this is a very bad idea.

Comment: `user A ssh into the vm the user's account will automatically be created`....if the account is not created beforehand, the user won't be able to `ssh` (login)..you need to create the potential accounts before they can login and use..

Comment: can i not modify ssh somehow to kick off a script that creates the user account and then the user can ssh a second time and this time it would work?

Comment: I suggest you just create a list of users , and create user accounts from list. Let me just find the answer I've posted some time ago on this topic

Comment: Here you go: http://askubuntu.com/q/633695/295286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like a challenge. Yes you can do this, if you are willing to let the
first ssh fail.  The following script (which I actually tested) tails the
sshd log, which by default (on my system) produces lines like this on a
failed ssh login:

```
Jun 20 21:06:35 home sshd[18163]: Invalid user dummy from ::1
```

When such a line is matched, the user id (dummy in this example) is
extracted and a user account is created with a encrypted password which is the
same as the user id (dummy).  A second attempt to login will now work.

```
# encrypt a cleartext password given as arg
cryptpw(){
        perl -e '
        my $pw = "'"$1"'";
        my $salt = join("",("a".."z")[rand 26,rand 26]);
        printf "%s\n", crypt($pw,$salt);'
}

sudo journalctl --no-pager -lfu sshd | 
while read line
do    if [[ "$line" =~ "Invalid user "([^ ]*) ]]
      then  newuser=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
            pw=$(cryptpw "$newuser")
            sudo useradd "$newuser" -p "$pw"
      fi
done
```

The user might like to then copy their key to the remote:

```
ssh-copy-id dummy@host
```

If they dont have a key yet, first do:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re, crypt, subprocess

with open('/var/log/auth.log') as logfile, open('/etc/passwd') as passfile:
    given_usernames = []
    for line in logfile:
        name = re.search(r'(?<= Invalid user ).*?(?= from)', line)
        if name:
            given_usernames.append(name.group())

    current_usernames = []
    for line in passfile:
         current_usernames.append(re.search(r'^[^:]+', line).group())

    for i in given_usernames:
        if i not in current_usernames:
            password = crypt.crypt(i + str(123), 'foobar12')
            subprocess.call('sudo useradd -m -p {0} {1}'.format(password, i).split())
```

- When a user try to login into a computer via `ssh` who does not have an existing account will be denied to login and this incident will be recorded in the `/var/log/auth.log` file having a line e.g.:

  ```
  Jun 21 01:11:03 my_hostname sshd[17763]: Invalid user foobar from 192.168.4.2
  ```
- we will exploit this line to extract the username provided to create an account for that user so that from next time the user can login without any problem
- We have used the password as the username given plus `123` (the salt is `foobar12`) i.e. if a username is `spamegg` the password will be `spamegg123`. You can change it and the salt to any value you want and of course the user must change the password after login for the first time
- In this approach all the usernames from the `/var/log/auth.log` file are taken into a list and similarly all usernames from `/etc/passwd` are also taken in a list.
- Then we have checked if the entered username exists already, if not then the user is created with the password mentioned earlier.
- You can run it as a `cron` job to make sure the usernames get added automatically.