# create multiple users from csv file and communicate them the password

Tags: password, adduser, useradd

I have to create multiple users in an Ubuntu environment from a csv file that  lists their names and password. I am using the following tutorial

[Import users from CSV file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633695/import-users-from-csv-file)

But I am not been able to run newsusers command successfully. I get the following ERROR message

```
newusers: group 'tom' is a shadow group, but does not exist in /etc/group
newusers: line 1: can't create group
newusers: error detected, changes ignored
```

Here is the format of my csv file

```
tom:password1::::/home/tom:
danny:password2::::/home/danny:
```

Also note that i have a csv file not : delimited file. I am also wondering how to communicate the password to multiple users if they are more than 100.

The output from running sudo grpck -r is

```
$sudo grpck -r
no matching group file entry in /etc/group
delete line 'tom:*::'? No
grpck: no changes
```

Please note that if i don't specify home directory like /home/tom in the csv file, it is NOT created. Is there a way to create it by default?

Thanks

After deleting Tom per @steeldriver's suggestion, when i run the newusers command, i get the following

```
$ sudo newusers < test.txt 
[sudo] password for oper: 
newusers: (user tom) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
newusers: (line 1, user tom) password not changed
newusers: (user danny) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
newusers: (line 2, user danny) password not changed
```

Comment: It's possible there's a mismatch between the group file and its shadow: can you run `sudo grpck -r` and [edit] your post to include any output please?

Comment: So, my guess is that you followed the first, top answer, where it says "You will need to create a file with this format:" and created the file where you specified the group for that user, is that correct  ?

Comment: @steeldriver  The post is updated per your suggestion

Comment: @Serg The post is updated

Comment: Well if group `tom` is just something you created as a test, then you can run `grpck` again without the `-r` and answer 'Yes' when prompted to delete it.

Comment: @steeldriver. Thanks now i get the following when i run $ sudo newusers < test.txt 
[sudo] password for oper: 
newusers: (user tom) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
newusers: (line 1, user tom) password not changed
newusers: (user danny) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
newusers: (line 2, user danny) password not changed

Comment: @steeldriver The post is updated. Please see the end of the post