# How to add users from .csv by specific field?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I'm trying to sort my users into specific servers, so what I'm trying to do at the moment is grab all the users by gender. Essentially I would have one server with all male users and one with all female users. The data in the file per line is read as so:

```
jimlee,7676,jim lee,sony,male,8912,1543,33:44
```

The command I'm using below grabs the first field and then adds the user. However my goal is to add a specific gender only and create a user for them. So seeing how the fifth field is the gender field I know that using `-f5` will give me that field and would display all the users by gender but I'm not sure how to grab the name based on a specific field, in this case the fifth field (gender).

```
cut -d ',' -f1 file.csv | while read line; do sudo useradd "$line"; done
```

Comment: Its very clunky, but you could just use grep to pre-filter for male or female eg `grep male file.csv | cut -d ',' -f1 | while read line; do sudo useradd "$line"; done`

Comment: Unfortunately the word 'male' is in the word 'female' so doing male grabs all the users.

Comment: Good point! change the grep to `grep ,male,`

Comment: @NickSillito then `grep -w male` would help, so it just matches the full word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Carrying over from my previous answer in your other question [How to grab characters before comma in a list and export to a script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/880179/295286) , use awk with `$FIELD == "word"`. Here male and female are set in field 5

```
awk -F',' '$5=="male" {command=sprintf("useradd \"%s\" ",$1); system(command) }' input.txt
```

You can do same for "female"

Comment: I think you need to add `-F ,` after "awk", and `command=` before "sprintf"

Comment: Yes. Wrote it out by hand because I'm on phone. I'll fix that

Comment: @Serg don't you still need to assign the `sprintf` result to the `command` variable?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, another thing that i fixed

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
sudo awk -F , '($5=="male") {system("useradd " $1)}' file.csv
```

Comment: parentheses ( and ) are not necessary

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for a pattern and fields may be inconsistent (ie if gender might not always be in the 5th field), you could use a `sed` way to grab the first field if `female` is in any field, for example:

```
sed -nr 's/^([^,]+),.*,female,.*/\1/p' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-n` don't print until we ask for something
- `-r` use ERE
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `^([^,]+),` save some characters before a comma at the start of each line (the first field)
- `,.*,` any number of any characters that might occur between two commas (so it doesn't matter how many fields there are between the first field and the pattern)
- `,female,` the line will only match if this pattern occurs
- `\1` the saved pattern in `()` from earlier
- `p` print only the lines that we changed

Answer (score 2):

It's probably quite straight forward to simply use a Bash loop with comma as [field separator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and calling `useradd` when required:

```
while IFS=, read user f2 f3 f4 gender _;
do
    if [ "$gender" == "male" ]; then
         sudo useradd "$user"
    fi
done < file
```

No need to call external commands such as awk or sed.